# Different popups for different textbox edits, possible?

Tags: c#, javascript, asp.net, ajax

I have an issue with a popup in Asp.net using AJAX modalpoup extender. Is it possible to show one kind of popup when the user edits few textboxes and the other kind of popup for the remaining textboxes.

I guess it is possible with some javascript function. Could someone help me out?

Ex: Only when txtbox1's value is changed, it should show me popup1  when the save button is clicked. Or else popup2.

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

This might be something that is limited by the fact that you're using ASP.net's modulapopup.  Have you tried looking into [jQuery](http://docs.jquery.com/Main_Page)?

For example, you could assign event handlers to the specific buttons/textboxes and have them trigger different events - which you would then handle accordingly, i.e. displaying different popups.  Take a look at jQuery UI, [specifically their Dialog demo](http://jqueryui.com/demos/dialog/).

Comment: In general the ASP.NET Ajax framework has proven to be very... problematic. Use JQuerry. The JQuery UI's Dialog is excellent, and so is the Fancybox plugin. They are easy to customize, have multiple events (PreLoad, LoadComplete, BeforeClose, Close, etc...) and so forth (keep in mind that those events are for illustrative purpose only, the actual events vary by plugin). They are significantly easier to work with and much "lighter" on both the server and the browser.